# PyMC3: When using the shape parameter for time series, is time on the row or column axis?

Tags: pymc, pymc3

I want to sample multiple time series of the same length in PyMC3. If I have code that reads:

```
with model:
    z = pm.GaussianRandomWalk('z', sd=1, shape=(100, 10))
```

Does this read "100 time series of length 10 each", or "10 time series of length 100 each"?